# How to clear previous searched gif before adding new gif's?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a GIF API in JavaScript. What happened is every time I search for another GIF it is just adding to my previously searched GIF except if I refresh it. I tried to use `imagesEl.innerHTML = '';` before the start of `forEach` code block but I realized it doesn't work. I also tried to use the if statement right after the end `forEach` code block but it doesn't work or maybe because I coded it wrong. Any comment will help! And I am sorry if some of my sentences are incorrect and I clearly understand that I should explain them well for an accurate solution, it is because English is not my first language.

```js
const formEl = document.querySelector('form');
const loaderEl = document.querySelector('.loader');
const mainContainer = document.querySelector('.container')
const imgContainer = document.querySelector('.img-container')

function showLoader() {
    loaderEl.style.display = 'block';
}

function hideLoader() {
    loaderEl.style.display = 'none';
    loaderEl.innerHTML = '';
}


formEl.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    const input = formEl.querySelector('input[name="input"]').value;
    
    if (input.length >= 1){ 
        showLoader();
        performSearch(input);
    } else {
       hideLoader(input);   
    }
    e.target.reset();
    
});

function performSearch(search) {

    const gifCount = 10;
    const apiKey = 'VL071LzBWMdYPAyxErdI1d0YPs406vB5';
    const url = `https://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?api_key=${apiKey}&q=${search}&limit=${gifCount}&offset=0&rating=pg-13&lang=en&bundle=messaging_non_clips`;

    fetch(url)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((info) => {
        console.log(info.data)
        const giftData = info.data;
        
        giftData.forEach((e) => {
       
            // imagesEl.innerHTML = '';
            //create a div with classlist of images
            const imagesEl = document.createElement('div');
            imagesEl.classList.add('images');
            //inside images div create img to store the gifs.
            const img = document.createElement('img');
            img.setAttribute("src", e.images.fixed_height_downsampled.url);
            
            // append all
            imagesEl.appendChild(img);
            imgContainer.appendChild(imagesEl);
     
            //if(e > 10){
             imagesEl.innerHTML = '';}
            hideLoader();

            });
        });
    };
```

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background-color: #7C9D96;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 'Roboto';
}

.container {
    position: relative; 
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    max-width: 1600px;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 50px 0;

}

input {
    height: 80px;
    width: 800px;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
}



input:focus {
    color: #353535;
}

.search-container {
    margin: auto 50px;
    width: 100%;

}


.btn {
    height: 80px;
    width: 200px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #353535;
}

.btn:active {
    background-color: #749BC2;
    transition: .3s;
}

.loader {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
    left: 40%;
    display: none;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 30px solid #0B666A;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-bottom: 30px solid white;
    animation: rotate .3s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes rotate {
    0% {
        rotate: 0deg;
    }
    100% {
        rotate: 360deg;
    }

}

.img-container {
    width: 100%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px, 1fr));
    margin: 20px;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.images {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 15px;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #F4F2DE;
}

.images:hover {
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    transition: .5s;
}

.images:hover:after{
    transition: .5s;
}

.images img {
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: contain;
    height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

        <div class="search-container">
            <form>
                <input type="text" name="input" class="text" placeholder="Ex. Happy" autocomplete="off">
                <button class="btn">Search</button>
            </form>
        </div>

        <div class="loader"></div>

        <div class="img-container">
            <!-- <div class="images">
                <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/137/200/300" alt="">
            
            </div> -->
           
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: so set it to be empty `imgContainer.innerHTML = '';`

Comment: Hi. I already did that. But what happens is only 1 gif will appear instead of 10.

Comment: Well then you are doing it in the loop and not outside of it....

Comment: Can you explain it more?

Comment: `imgContainer.innerHTML = '';   giftData.forEach((e) => { .... }`

Comment: Can you explain what exactly you want to achieve and how your current approach is failing?

Answer (score 1):

This is semi-psudo code, but outlines what needs to happen. You should clear out the div before populating it with children. you can't evaluate 'e' as an integer ie if e<10... the list is already up to 10 in length, just iterate through it and create your img elements. :D

```js
async function performSearch(search) {

  const gifCount = 10;
  const apiKey = 'VL071LzBWMdYPAyxErdI1d0YPs406vB5';
  const url = `https://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?api_key=${apiKey}&q=${search}&limit=${gifCount}&offset=0&rating=pg-13&lang=en&bundle=messaging_non_clips`;

  //need refs to put things somewhere
  const imagesEl = document.querySelector('.images')
  if imagesEl == null {
    imagesEl = document.createElement('div');
    imagesEl.classList.add('images');
    // VVVV NOT QUITE SURE HOW TO SELECT THIS VVVV
    imgContainer.appendChild(imagesEl);
    // ^^^^^^^^^
  }

  await fetch(url)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((info) => {
        console.log(info.data)
        const giftData = info.data;
        // the giftData is 10 long already
        // clear the existing results!
        imagesEl.innerHTML = '';

        giftData.forEach((e) => {
            //inside images div create img to store the gifs.
            const img = document.createElement('img');
            img.setAttribute("src", e.images.fixed_height_downsampled.url);
            // append all
            imagesEl.appendChild(img);
          }
          // I suppose you might still need this?
          hideLoader();
        });
    });
};
```